# Find all zeroes $f(x) = 3x^{299}+2x^{222}-5 \in \mathbb{F}_{7}[x]$ in $\Bbb{F}_{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Find all zeroes $f(x) = 3x^{299}+2x^{222}-5 \in \mathbb{F}_{7}[x]$ in $\Bbb{F}_{7}$. I know that we can just test out all the values, because the field is small. But I'm interested. Is there a more optimal algorithm to solve that problem?

Comment: Remember $x^7=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb F_7$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  If I'm not mistaken that would mean if $n = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i 7^i$ then $x^n = x^{\sum a_i}$.  Correct?  So $x^{299=49*6+5}=x^{6+5=7+4}=x^{1+4} = x^5$

Comment: @fleablood Yup, for $x\in\Bbb F_7.$ If $x$ is an indeterminate (like the variable $x\in\Bbb F_7[x]$), it is no longer true.

Comment: Ugh.. brain fart.  $\sum a_i \equiv n \mod (7-1)$ so that's trivial.  I was thrown by the $x^6 \ne 1$ if $\gcd(x,7)\ne 1$  But we can simply do $x^n = x^6$ if $n\equiv 0 \mod 6$ and $x^n = x^k$ if $n \equiv k\mod 6$ other wise. ($7$ being prime it's not an issue as only $x=0$ is so that $x^6 \ne 1$ but for rings with zero divisors...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Clearly $\bar{0}$ is not the solution.
So the solutions are from $\mathbb{F}_7^*$. Since the order is $6$. We can reduce $x^{299} = x^5$ and $x^{222} = \bar{1}$ so the we have just to solve for $3x^5 +2-5 = 3x^5-3$.

So we have to solve for $x^5-1$ which is easy to solve. The answer is $1$ clearly because $5$ is coprime to the order of the group $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ which is $6$.

Comment: Since $x$ is an indeterminate, it's false that $x^{299}=x^5$. What's true is that, for every $a\in\mathbb{F}_7^*$, $a^6=1$.

Comment: We are taking x from $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ and $x^6 = 1 = x^{6*49} = x^{294}$. So multipling $x^5$ will give $x^{299} = x^5$.

Comment: If $a\in\mathbb{F}_7^*$ is a root, then $a^{299}=a^5$ and so on. So the roots of $3x^{299}+2x^{222}-5$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$ are the same as the roots of $3x^5-3$, but these are *different* polynomials.

Comment: So had shrinit singh said $3x^{299} +2x^{222}-5$ and $3x^5 - 3$ have the same solutions would it have been acceptable.  To be fair, nowhere in the post was it said they were the same polynomial.  I suppose $x^{299}=x^5$ implies that but in context of speaking of *solutions* is refering to $x$ as a value rather than an indeterminate that serious a sin?  It might be....